# in gradle, what is the equivalent of generateJava in kotlin project?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, graphql, netflix-dgs

In the netflix grapql [code gen documentation](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#__code_7) what is the equivalent of `generateJava` in a kotlin project build script. And how can I specify the directory of generated codes?
Also in the below code, should i add all my domain types in the collection?

```
typeMapping = ["MyGraphQLType": "com.mypackage.MyJavaType"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `generateJava` in a Kotlin project, it will generate Kotlin code by default.

> Note that on a Kotlin project, the generateJava task generates Kotlin code by default (yes the name is confusing) in https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/